# Simple python script to stitch images into movie failing with incorrect context

Tags: python, animation, video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to write a simple script that adds png images to the video seqeuence editor, and stitches them into a movie. However, between the blender API and all of the old documentation that's floating around online, I can't seem to get it to work. Here's my code:

```py
import bpy
import os, glob


img_dir = 'my/img/dir'

# set movie render settings
resx = 1024
resy = 350

bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.resolution_x = resx
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.resolution_y = resy
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.resolution_percentage = 100

scene = bpy.data.scenes[0]
editor = scene.sequence_editor_create()

# get image files
image_files = []
for _file in os.listdir(path=img_dir):
    if _file.endswith('.png'):
        image_files.append(_file)

context = bpy.context

# add to sequencer
img_strip = [{'name':i} for i in image_files]
frames = len(image_files)
frame_end = frames - 1  # offset for python counting

a = bpy.ops.sequencer.image_strip_add(directory=img_dir, files=img_strip,
    channel=1, frame_start=0, frame_end=frame_end)

strip_name = file[0].get("name")
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_end = frames
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.image_settings.file_format = 'AVI_JPEG'
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = out_dir
bpy.ops.render.render( animation=True )
```

with output:

```
line 32, in <module>
    channel=1, frame_start=0, frame_end=frame_end)
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.sequencer.image_strip_add.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

What does this error mean? And how might I go about modifying my code?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14728/how-to-find-out-why-context-is-incorrect

Answer (score 3):

**Ditch the operator.**

Have updated the code from

[Importing multiple movie clips inside one directory via script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111446/importing-multiple-movie-clips-inside-one-directory-via-script)

- look at all images in a path
- glob on "*.png"
- to use `pathlib.Path`

**Adding each image as a strip.**

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

# glob all movie files from
dir_path = "/home/batfinger/Pictures"
img_dir = Path(dir_path)
glob = "*.png"
frame_duration = 24
files = sorted(list(img_dir.glob(glob)))

# get sequence editor
scene = bpy.context.scene
#scene.sequence_editor_clear()
sed = scene.sequence_editor_create()
seq = sed.sequences

# add movie strips
for i, fp in enumerate(files):
    ms = seq.new_image(
            name=fp.name,
            filepath=str(fp),
            channel=i + 1,
            frame_start= i * frame_duration + 1 ,
            
            )
    ms.frame_final_duration = frame_duration
    # print some details
    print("%s ch: %d fs: %3.1f len: %d" %
            (fp.name, i + 1, ms.frame_start, ms.frame_final_duration)
            )
```

**Adding images as sequence to one strip.**

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

dir_path = "/home/batfinger/Pictures"
img_dir = Path(dir_path)
glob = "*.png"
frame_duration = 24
files = sorted(list(img_dir.glob(glob)))

# get sequence editor
scene = bpy.context.scene
#scene.sequence_editor_clear()
sed = scene.sequence_editor_create()
seq = sed.sequences
duration = len(files)
# add image strip using first
fp = files.pop(0)
imstrip = seq.new_image(
    name=fp.name,
    filepath=str(fp),
    frame_start=1,
    channel=1,
    )
# add the elements 
while files:
    imstrip.elements.append(files.pop(0).name)
    
imstrip.frame_final_duration = duration
imstrip.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

[As batFINGER suggested](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204268/simple-python-script-to-stitch-images-into-movie-failing-with-incorrect-context#comment343802_204268), you get this error because you try run a function in a context that is not suitable. If you click on the run/start-button in the text editor, the context of the running code is the `TEXT_EDITOR`, not the `SEQUENCE_EDITOR`. Therefore, you would have to switch context.

This can be done as follows ([see response of eceathar for the original solution)](https://blenderartists.org/t/add-images-with-bpy-ops-sequencer-image-strip-add/695710/2):

```
area = bpy.context.area
old_type = area.type
area.type = 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR'

# call the image_strip_add here and other functions

area.type = old_type
```

Further reading: [poll() failed, context incorrect? - Example: bpy.ops.view3d.background_image_add()](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add)