# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ui_type' when running blender using CLI

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video

My code runs fine when I run the script directly in blender. However if run the file headless in the terminal I get this error and the animation renders the default cube instead of my animation:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ui_type'
```

Here is my CLI command:

```
'/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender -b /Users/myname/Desktop/folder/videoRender.blend -a"
```

Blender text editor code:

```
import bpy, sys, os

bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR'

#create image sequences and import screens of there are more than one file
if (len(files) == 1):
    
    # set duration to 300
    duration = 300
    
    for index in range(5):
        filesFolder = folder + "/" + str((index+1)) + '/renderedFiles/'
        bpy.ops.sequencer.image_strip_add(
            directory=filesFolder, 
            files=files[1], 
            show_multiview=False,
            frame_start= (filesCount * index), 
            frame_end=filesCount * index, 
            channel=5
        )
```

Comment: Been asked often before. Background mode is also known as _"headless"_ because it loads no UI. Hence there is no context area (it's `None` hence the error).

Comment: Hey @batFINGER, I understand however do you know how I can change the context area in headless mode please? I can't find a solution after looking through here.

Comment: See my answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204268/simple-python-script-to-stitch-images-into-movie-failing-with-incorrect-context  same applies to image strip... _ditch the operator_

Comment: Thanks so much I really appreciate your response! I'll check it out and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Wow thanks so much @batFINGER, it works perfectly! I'll write this as an answer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @batFINGER, his solution to ditch the operator worked! Here's the answer: [Simple python script to stitch images into movie failing with incorrect context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204268/simple-python-script-to-stitch-images-into-movie-failing-with-incorrect-context).