# Importing images as frames in bulk

Tags: import, image, file-browser

I have a massive folder of 3300 images as part of a multi-hour timelapse of a flower opening and closing. Fairly basic stuff. I want to render them as a 4K-movie with each image being one frame at 60fps.
I cannot find a way to import the image files this way, neither drag&drop from the File explorer nor with the in-blender explorer. If I try those options, it just puts the first file in the folder or selection onto the timeline. is there a way to import them nonetheless?
Blender version: 2.93.3, fresh installation
OS: Windows 10 64bit
File format: JPG
And while I'm here, what rendering engine would be best for rendering that movie (or purely 2D movies in general), given it's no 3D information at all?

Comment: TBH: I'd recommend using davinci resolve for that kind of task, the vse is pretty slow.

Comment: Via script https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204268/simple-python-script-to-stitch-images-into-movie-failing-with-incorrect-context would require edit filepath and type from png to jpg (to match yours)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, it helped. I normally do use DaVinci Resolve, but the free version can't output videos above FHD resolution.